# How to set focus on dynamic input field?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to set focus on an input field.

After pressing the button, this method works for me.

```
    function createNewDiv() {
      document.getElementById('myButton').blur(); ---- here I remove the focus from the button. Because the browser writes an error that an element with focus already exists
     
      const body = document.createElement('template');
      body.innerHTML = `
        <div>
          <input type="text" tabindex="2" onblur="document.getElementById('inputId').focus()" autofocus="autofocus" class="someClass"  id="inputId" placeholder="some text"  required>
        </div>
      `;

...
}
```

It creates a block that contains an input field. I want this input to be in focus.
In the safari browser it works and the focus is set. But in google chrome does not work.

Comment: See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus) for more info about focus

Comment: You create an element `const body = document.createElement('template');` but where do you append/insert it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore your supplied code because it is incomplete rubbish with important parts missing, invalid quotes, and many errors!

So I'll just inform that in the Chromium + Mozilla world, to set focus on an element we do this...

```
e.focus(); e.select();
```

Comment: Given you comment in your answer perhaps you meant to vote to "Close" in stead of answer

Comment: Do as you please fellas, I’m just passing through trying to help 2-3 people before returning to work.